# Gears and rotation

Tags: gears, mechanisms

I have to project a mechanism that transform a rotation of $30 \pi/\text s$ from a engine in a rotation of $(\pi/4)/\text s$.

One of the gears should be 120x bigger than the other, but this is too much.

The gears should have a ray $< 30\text{ cm}$.

How can I create this mechanism?

Comment: Two stage reduction, worm gears, harmonics gears. There are many options.

Comment: An epicyclic reduction unit may work well...

Comment: A harmonic drive could do this nicely in a small package and with near zero backlash and high torque.

Answer (score 1):

In practice probably the best solution is to find an off the shelf gearbox with the reduction ratio that you require for example  :

https://www.ondrivesus.com/gearboxes-speed-reducers **(not a recommendation)**

Unless you have specialist knowledge designing and manufacturing a high ratio gearbox from scratch is unlikely to be very cost effective.

That way you just need to find one which meets your requirements for reduction ration and torque capacity.